# Objective C Beginner: where to put code that needs to be executed once in UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have `UITableViewController` where I need to put initialization code only once to populate data source. in which method to put this code.

I tried with `viewWillAppear:` method, but it get executed every time view appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display things only once that the View has comed on screen, then yeah. go for it. Otherwise you also have ViewdidLoad or ViewWillAppear if you have to arrange things before the view begins the transition to slide in.

All of these methods will be executed every time from the tableView you tap on a row.

anyway the pattern you are trying to achieve is called singleton, you can find out about it more over here

[What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in `viewDidLoad` and it will be only once.

Answer (score 0):

The `- (void)viewDidLoad` method is probably the place you want use. It gets called once the view controller has finished doing its loading code (either by loading a XIB or by calling `loadView`).